# reading correct range of values from tif files in R

Tags: r

I am trying to open a .tif file containing values for canopy height. In my code, the values read are in the range (0,255). However, the provider of the file believes the values are in the range (0,40) and probably my software (which is R) is expanding the values. 
Please help and suggest how to tackle this programming issue and get the desired range without expanding. See the lines I wrote to read the file.

```
remove(list=ls())
library(raster)
read_file<-as.matrix(raster("veght_Part_d_7.tif")) #filename of attached image
min(read_file)
max(read_file) # returns 255 but supposedly return 40
```

[image]
canopy height values in tif format

Comment: the original file can be downloaded from the weblink: http://josh.yosh.org/datamodels/Simard_Pinto_3DGlobalVeg_JGR.tif.gz

Comment: I would get the provider to give you evidence rather than beliefs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with your data, not r. I just opened the tif in arcgis to check in an alternative platform and the values are evenly distributed from 0 to 255, and do not concentrate at all between 0 and 40.

Comment: thanks for helping me on this, quick question: did u check the original file from weblink or sample file I uploaded?

Comment: I used the weblink you provided, which yielded a monstrous (nearly 1gb tif)- almost choked my computer.

Comment: thats great help, thanks for your support. sorry for the large file size.

Comment: it's a 8 bit image. a canopy height data would normally be a float.